# Swap Memory Visibility On The /proc/swaps Command Output

Tags: command-line, swap

Swap memory information can be get by using `cat /proc/swaps` command.

It looks like there are several swap memory types such as file and partition.

Is there any situations that there is swap memory (file, partition or any other type) but it is not visible on the `cat /proc/swaps` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. Any swap memory that is currently available to the system is listed in `cat /proc/swaps`. In order to be available for use as swap by the system, a swap partition or swap file must be registered as such in `/etc/fstab`.